# AND Condition (from array)

Tags: php, mysql

To populate dropdown from database I use a simply query like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM admin_users
LEFT JOIN account ON account_id = user_account_id
AND user_active = 1
```

Now I'm like to populate list with IN option to have on dropdown only users with access to 'area'

Area ID is serialized in database and to get array I use

```
$bar = unserialize(base64_decode($user_areas));
```

Now, I'm like when open page i have dropdown only with users than have access to area. There is a way to filter users directly from query ??

```
SELECT *
FROM admin_users
LEFT JOIN account ON account_id = user_account_id

>>>>> WHERE area_id IN ($foo) <<<<

AND user_active = 1
```

Comment: You have to  get user list before

Comment: isn't that supposed to be a SQL question instead of PHP? not sure to follow here?

Answer (score 0):

you have to "implode" your array $bar to get an inline string with IDs, like this:

```
$bar = array(7, 9, 27, 44); // These numbers are Area IDs
```

Then get the inline string with the [implode()](http://php.net/implode) function:

$inline = implode($bar, ',')

Finally, concatenate in your query:

```
select ...
>>>>> WHERE area_id IN ($inline) <<<<
```

Comment: If you don't want to meet little Bobby Tables, don't neglect escaping.

Answer (score 0):

using [subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html) :

```
SELECT *
FROM admin_users
LEFT JOIN account ON account_id = user_account_id
WHERE area_id IN (
    SELECT aria_id from `user_area_table` [where clause if needed]
)
AND user_active = 1
```